# Lambda Function exits unsuccessfully

Tags: java, aws-lambda

I am having a weird problem while creating a Java Lambda function which has a primary function of JWT token validation. I am using terraform for the creation of the lambda and uploading my Jar file to the s3 for now. The below is the token validation block

```
public boolean validate(String token) throws Exception {

    try {

        Jws<Claims> claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey("mysigningkey").parseClaimsJws(token);

        if (claims.getBody().getExpiration().before(new Date())) {

            throw new Exception("Token expired");
        }

        return true;

    } catch (JwtException | IllegalArgumentException e) {

        throw new InvalidJwtAuthenticationException("Some exception");
    }
}
```

This line is causing the problem

```
Jws<Claims> claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey("mysigningkey").parseClaimsJws(token);
```

I have put the **Exception** and **Error** in the catch block but it's not printing any message. But this line fails to execute. I tried to manually create the function in the AWS console with the same Jar file and the same code worked fine.

Any idea of this behavior? Or any debugging strategies? On the cloud watch logs it just printed execution was not successful and no other specific error messages.

The following message is written to the Cloudwatch logs:

```
REPORT RequestId: ####### Duration: 1835.00 ms Billed Duration: 1900 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 93 MB Init Duration: 349.72 ms
```

Timeout set as 3 Seconds

Comment: Please explain what actually happens? Where do you see an error? How do you know it doesn't work? Also, consider if this is really related to Terraform. Can the question be more generic?

Comment: I see the logs in the Lambda console. It was not executed after the line I mentioned above. No specific errors but it just printed execution was unsuccessful. Anyway, I have found the reason and fixed it. It is not related to terraform.The explanation is given as an answer below

Comment: From your answer, it sounds like you're getting some information in the Cloudwatch logs (Memory and time). Please provide this

Comment: REPORT RequestId: ####### Duration: 1835.00 ms Billed Duration: 1900 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 93 MB Init Duration: 349.72 ms

Timeout set as 3 Seconds

Answer (score 0):

This was due to a timeout issue. The default timeout on Lambda when creating is 3 seconds because the token validation takes more time Lambda was exiting reaching the time limit. Increased the timeout to 15 sec and it is working fine. But I have not seen any error message in the logs which is hinting me that it is because of the timeout

Comment: You can't mitigate cold starts in this way. A single instance of Lambda is only alive for 15 minutes. You will get a cold start for every new instance or when the instance expires (after 15 mins). Changing the memory configuration will likely invalidate the current warm instances anyway.

Comment: Are you sure you're not hitting the Lambda timeout? A higher memory allocation has a side effect of giving you a higher spec. EC2 instance and therefore faster CPU processing, which could mean your Lambda is completing more quickly.

Comment: i am not mitigating cold start by increasing the memory. My point is when i increased the memory from 128 MB to 512 MB lambda function executed successfully. I was looking for the reason for this.

Comment: You decreased the memory and it still worked. Therefore, the problem is not memory-related.

Comment: Yes, by considering your point I increased the timeout to 15 sec and memory to 128 MB. That worked hence the problem was timeout not memory

Comment: Apologies for seeming pedantic, but your question and answer are very valuable, so I'm just trying to get the most detail out to help others in the future 

Comment: I agree with that , that is how we are finding the "actual problem" :)